# If-Elif-Else Python (Discount Scenario)

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm working on this program that gives discount depending on how much the customer has purchased.

The direction is as follows:
 certain online store gives discounts based on the total amount of the purchase:

```
        If the purchase total is over $50, a 5% discount is applied

        If the purchase total is over $100, a 10% discount is applied

        If the purchase total is over $500,  a 15% discount is applied
```

Use an if-elif-else chain to calculate the purchase amount after applying any discount. For your demo, use a purchase of $499.99.

And this is what I created so far, but it doesn't seem to run properly, and I was wondering what I can do to make my code better and perhaps if I am using the if-elif-else code properly. Thank you all in advance.

```
if total_cost>=10:    
   if give_shopper_5percent_discount():
     print"You have won a discount"
     total_cost -= discount
   candidate_prime =True

elif total_cost>100:
   if give_shopper_10percent_discount():
     print"You have won a discount"
     total_cost -= discount
   candidate_prime =True


else total_cost>=500:
   if give_shopper_15percent_discount():
     print"You have won a discount"
     total_cost -= discount
   candidate_prime =True
```

Comment: You need to fix your indentation, it matters in Python, so if we can't see it in your question, we don't know what your real code is. You also need to define precisely what "doesn't seem to run properly" means, and provide the definitions of `give_shopper_5percent_discount()` and friends, and generally show a program that people can run to replicate your problem.

Comment: narrow down the problem spots (is python throwing an error?) and add a liberal number of print statements to see whats going on. For instance, I see `total_cost -= discount` a lot, but discount is never calculated and should be different in each case.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths. Thanks I just edited it. I'm just confused on if this format is how if-elif-else format works. Am I supposed to use two elifs functions and save else for something else? I'm confused because it looks like I need at least three options to use it.

Comment: If total_cost>=10 is false, how can total_cost>100 be true?

Comment: I never set anything to false. I don't get what you mean

Comment: If total_cost is smaller than 10, how can it be larger than 100? I guess you will never enter the `elif` case. The `elif` condition is only checked if the condition in `if` is false. I think you'll need to switch the conditions(together with the codes inside).

Comment: Shoot. I'm so lost. Would you be able to show me what you mean? If Elif Else statement has three different scenarios as my case, so each number would act differently right?

Comment: It should be in this order: `If total_cost>=500: .... elif total_cost>=100: .... elif total_cost>=50 ... else ....`

Comment: Oh ok so just switch the order, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `total_cost` limit is wrong according to your description. And you should not use else before `total_cost >= 500`

Try this:

```
total_cost = int(input('Please enter a total_cost:'))
if total_cost>=500:    

   print"You have won a discount by 15 percent"
   total_cost *= 0.85



elif total_cost>100:

   print"You have won a discount by 10 percent"
   total_cost *= 0.9



elif total_cost>=50:

   print"You have won a discount by 5 percent"
   total_cost *= 0.95

else:
   print 'you total cost is not in the range of discount!'
print 'Now the total cost is ', total_cost
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what was thinking. So I use the else function if no discounts are available. However, when I run the code it is saying that total_cost is not defined in the first line, and I'm guessing that would be problematic for the other lines as well.

Comment: HELP? I have three total_cost lines and they are set to discount. I don't get it.

Comment: They are not set to discount. `total_cost -= discount` means `total_cost = total_cost - discount`

Comment: @python2learn Hi, you need to set a value to total_cost before first if so that 'total_cost -= discount' will take effect.

Comment: int(input(Enter total_cost))                                          I'm having trouble. Are you saying I need to ask them a question? Perhaps the code I entered above? total cost already has the total cost and discount correct? Or would this fix this?total_cost = total_cost - discount

Comment: @python2learn I'm not sure what you did in function like give_shopper_15percent_discount(). Check my update in the answer. It won't raise total_cost not exist error.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it still is giving me the same error "name 'give_shopper_5percent_discount' is not defined". Would you be able to see what you get for $499.99? Thank you

Comment: @python2learn I think give_shopper_5percent_discount is no use for you. Check my latest answer. I'm sure there is no error any more.

Comment: Thank you. It tells me that I have won a discount as it should, but how do I include the actual discounted price? It doesn't seem to print that.

Comment: Thank you so much. What did you change to print out the discounted price?

Comment: @python2learn I print out the final price after discounting in the last line.

Comment: @python2learn If there is no more question, please accept it as an answer. :)

Comment: Also if you don't mind and have the time of course, would you please take a look this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031127/if-elif-else-chain-to-classify-triangle-python?noredirect=1#comment40774681_26031127        Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the biggest discount first, otherwise you grant much more discounts as intended ;-)

```
if total_cost>=500:
  ...
elif total_cost>=100:
  ...
elif total_cost>=10:
  ...
else: 
  pass
```

Comment: I think this is the main issue. In an if/elif/else test you usually want to test the most strict condition first. Otherwise you need to have more complicated conditions (like `if 10 <= total_cost < 100`).

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is out of wack. It matters in python. (try this?)

```
if give_shopper_5percent_discount():
    print"You have won a discount"
    total_cost -= discount
    candidate_prime =True

elif total_cost>100:
     if give_shopper_10percent_discount():
     print"You have won a discount"
     total_cost -= discount
      candidate_prime =True

else total_cost>=500:
      if give_shopper_15percent_discount():
      print"You have won a discount"
      total_cost -= discount
      candidate_prime =True
```

also for discount try multiplting instead of subtracting.

Comment: I was also missing a line. Here, I just changed to this, but I keep getting an error.                                                          if total_cost>=10:    
   if give_shopper_5percent_discount():
     print"You have won a discount"
     total_cost -= discount
   candidate_prime =True

elif total_cost>100:
   if give_shopper_10percent_discount():
     print"You have won a discount"
     total_cost -= discount
   candidate_prime =True


else total_cost>=500:
   if give_shopper_15percent_discount():
     print"You have won a discount"
     total_cost -= discount
   candidate_prime =True

Comment: Shoot. I am having difficulty using indenting here on stack overflow. But I forgot to add if total_cost>=10: in the first line. But it is showing me that total_cost is not defined.

Comment: Do you have the whole code? Post it in first post. 

to indent code, 4 spaces

Comment: Ugh. I just tried but the formatting is killing me. But it's the code that m170897017 has shown above. I now get how to use that else function, but it doesn't seem to run. It is saying I have an error in my first line where total_cost is not defined.

Comment: I'm confused. I set total cost to be discount, am I correct? If not do I need to define it three different times since there are three different discounts?

Comment: before your if statement set

total_cost = 0

see what happens

Comment: It is still giving me that File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'total_cost' is not defined. I don't understand it.

Comment: post your code to pastebin.com (entire file) then i ll have a look

Comment: the problem is python doesnt know what Total_cost =?

Before if type "total_cost = 150. Then run it

Comment: SOrry. I'm confused. Why would you set it to equal? Its supposed to be greater. Would you be able to show me the code if it runs?

Comment: the problem is what is total cost of grocerries? does the user enter total cost of grocerries?

Comment: Thank you. Now I can get to the question line where they ask me for the input, but this comes up...NameError: name 'give_shopper_5percent_discount' is not defined

Comment: thats a function name, have you defined those functions? I think you need to rad your spe carefully because your not understanding programming concepts.