# If Elif Else Chain To Classify Triangle (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

```
a = input("Please Enter Side  A ") 
b = input("Please Enter Side  B") 
c = input("Please Enter Side  C ") 

d = a+b+c 

if d < (2*a) or d < (2*b) or d < (2*c): 
   print "Shame on you, that is not a triangle!" 
elif (a==b==c): 
   print "It's Equilateral"  
elif (a==b) or (a==c) or (b==c): 
   print "It's Isosceles"
```

I have the following assignment that I'm having a hard to grasp on.

> Ask the user to tell you the three angles of a triangle in degrees, minutes and seconds. Use an if-elif-else chain to classify the triangle:
>
> Compute the sum of the three angles. If the total of the angles equals 180° 0' 0"     [180 degrees, zero minutes, zero seconds], it is a Euclidean triangle. If the total of the angles exceeds 180° 0' 0", it cannot be a Euclidean triangle on a flat plane: it is “elliptical”, perhaps on a sphere, such as the surface a planet like that minor planet of an unremarkable sun in an obscure corner of a mediocre galaxy that is known as “Earth”. If the total of the angles is less than 180°, the triangle must be “hyperbolic”, on a concave surface, which might be the shape of our Universe. [For extra credit, you may resolve this question by drawing 2 parallel lines at least 732 gazillion light-years in each direction and determine if the lines in fact ever cross].
>
> In addition, classify the triangle as:
>
> Equilateral: all three angles are equal
>
> Isosceles: two and only two of the angles are equal
>
> Scalene: if it is neither equilateral nor isosceles
>
> Your program should say something like “That is a Euclidian Scalene Triangle” or “That is a Hyperbolic Equilateral Triangle”. You should tell the user what the total DMS (Degrees, Minutes, Seconds) is for the three angles.

My question and guess is that I just need to include if elif else function and this is what I have so far above. I tried to add the angles instead of the lengths of the side, but I'm getting an error. How do convert the measurement of the angles into if they are isosceles, equilateral? Any inputs would be appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

```
           (Deg)   (Min)   (Sec)
Angle A      29       0      30
Angle B      60      15      30
Angle C      90      44       0
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code (other than the fact that you seem to be asking for side lengths, rather than vertex angles). Are you getting an error? If so, post the traceback. Is your code giving the wrong answer? If so, please let us know the inputs you're trying and what the expected and observed outputs are.

Comment: I tried to add the angles but I am getting an error. Is the format right? I am trying to add these examples, but I cannot get it work.                       Angle A 29 (Dg) 0   (Min) 30  (Sec)
Angle B 60 15         30
Angle C 90 44          0

Answer (score 1):

I can only give you a sample. You need to edit this program by yourself to fit your requirement.

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
a[0] = float(input('Please enter degrees for a:'))
a[1] = float(input('Please enter minutes for a:'))
a[2] = float(input('Please enter seconds for a:'))
b[0] = float(input('Please enter degrees for b:'))
b[1] = float(input('Please enter minutes for b:'))
b[2] = float(input('Please enter seconds for b:'))
c[0] = float(input('Please enter degrees for c:'))
c[1] = float(input('Please enter minutes for c:'))
c[2] = float(input('Please enter seconds for c:'))


print 'Now for angle A, we have degrees: %f, minutes: %f, seconds: %f.' % (a[0], a[1], a[2])
print 'Now for angle B, we have degrees: %f, minutes: %f, seconds: %f.' % (b[0], b[1], b[2])
print 'Now for angle C, we have degrees: %f, minutes: %f, seconds: %f.' % (c[0], c[1], c[2])

a_in_de = a[0] + a[1]/60 + a[2]/60
b_in_de = b[0] + b[1]/60 + b[2]/60
c_in_de = c[0] + c[1]/60 + c[2]/60
summary = a_in_de + b_in_de + c_in_de
if summary == float(180):
    print "It's an Euclidean triangle"
elif summary > float(180):
    print "It's an elliptical."
elif summary < float(180):
    print "It's a hyperbolic."
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much. But how do I include the equilateral, isosceles, scalene triangles in addition to the eclidean, elliptical, hyperbolic triangles? For example how can I say isosceles elliptical triangle?

Comment: @python2learn You need to compare two of angles for isosceles as described in the question, 'Isosceles: two and only two of the angles are equal'. And then if this meets, print out the message.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you, but I think I get the hang of it. Would you be able to help me with this questions? It's regarding using the while function to calculate GPAs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128722/calculting-gpa-using-while-loop-python