# Calculting GPA using While Loop (Python)

Tags: python, while-loop

A GPA, or Grade point Average, is calculated by summing the grade points earned in a student’s courses and then dividing by the total units. The grade points for an individual course are calculated by multiplying the units for that course by the appropriate factor depending upon the grade received:

```
  A receives 4 grade points

  B receives 3 grade points

  C receives 2 grade points

  D receives 1 grade point

  F receives 0 grade point
```

Your program will have a while loop to calculate multiple GPAs and a while loop to collect individual grades (i.e. a nested while loop).

For your demo, calculate the GPA to 2 decimal places for these two course combinations:

```
 First Case:                5 units of A           4 units of B           3 units of C

 Second Case:           6 units of A           6 units of B           4 units of C
```

This is what I have so far....

```
todo = int(input("How many GPA's would you like to calculate? "))
while True: x in range (1, todo+1)
n = int(input("How many courses will you input? "))
totpoints = 0
totunits = 0

while True:  range(1, n+1)

grade = input("Enter grade for course: " )
if grade == 'A':
    grade = int(4)
if grade == 'B':
    grade = int(3)
if grade == 'C':
    grade = int(2)
if grade == 'D':
    grade = int(1)
if grade == 'F':
    grade = int(0)

units = int(input("How many units was the course? "))
totunits += units
points = grade*units
totpoints += points
GPA = totpoints / totunits

print("GPA is ", ("%.2f" % GPA))
print("total points = ", totpoints)
print("total units = ", totunits)
```

My question is how do I exactly incorporate the while function correctly? My code is not running correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a `while` loop because you're using a `for` loop instead. Which is usually more idiomatic and more readable, but if your assignment requires a `while` loop, you will have to rewrite it to use one.

Comment: In other words: you need to set a starting value for `x`, then use `while (some condition on x):`, then inside the loop update `x` in some way.

Comment: so do i just replace it with while? doesn't while function requir if else elif?

Comment: No, a `while` loop doesn't require an `if`/`else`. The `while` statement has a condition built in. You _can_ instead just use `while True:`, and use an `if (opposite of condition on x): break` or similar inside, and sometimes you have to, but usually that isn't necessary.

Comment: I did and now the code won't run. Would you be able to show me how?

Comment: You need to indent the code under the `while` statement, the same way you did previously with the `for` statement. Also, that `range(1, n+1)` doesn't fit anywhere. You need to do what I said before: create a starting value for `x` before the loop, use either `while (some condition on x):` instead of `while True:` (or, inside the loop, use `if (opposite condition on x): break`), and update `x` somewhere in the loop. You haven't done any of that.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you must know about Python is that is all about indentation. So make sure you indent your while blocks correctly. The syntax of the while statements is like:

> ```
> while <condition>:
>     do_something
> ```

The code inside the while block is executed if the condition is true. After executing the code the condition is checked again. If the condition is still true it will execute the block again, and so on and so forth until the condition is false. Once the condition is false it exits the while block and keeps executing the code after.

One last thing, Python does not have case statements like other programming languages do. But you can use a dictionary, so for example I've defined a dictionary to map the grades to points and remove the if statements from your code:

> ```
> gradeFactor = {'A':4, 'B': 3, 'C':2, 'D':1, 'F':0}
> todo = int(raw_input("How many GPA's would you like to calculate? "))
> while todo: 
>     n = int(raw_input("How many courses will you input? "))
>     totpoints = 0
>     totunits = 0
>     while n:  
>         grade = raw_input("Enter grade for course: " )
>         units = int(raw_input("How many units was the course? "))
>         totunits += units
>         points = gradeFactor[grade]*units
>         totpoints += points
>         n -= 1
>     GPA = float(totpoints) / totunits
>     print("GPA is ", ("%.2f" % GPA))
>     print("total points = ", totpoints)
>     print("total units = ", totunits)
>     todo -= 1
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I am having trouble running your code. When I run it, I get this error....Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined

Comment: If you are using Python 2.7 use `raw_input` instead of `input`. `input` tries to interpret the input as Python code. That's why you get that message. You shouldn't use it but in special cases. Also if you want to obtain decimals you must explicitly convert to `float` when calculating the `GPA = float(totpoints)/totunits`. Otherwise Python 2.7 performs floor division if both variables are integers.

Comment: Shoot. I don't know how to exactly change that as it seems to not run. So should I just run your code in what version of python? I don't have a complier so I use the online compiler.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked very well. I have another question. Would you be able to help me out? Also, how do I vote you for the answer? I'm new to the site. The link is here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151660/using-loop-to-find-brute-force-prime-numbers