# Using Loop to find Brute Force Prime Numbers

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write this program that uses looping where it finds Brute Force Prime Nu,beds using Mersenne. The direction is as follows.

> > > > A prime number is a number that is not evenly divisible by any other number (except,       trivially, 1). All known methods of determining whether a number is a prime number rely on brute force, that is, exhaustive testing of the possibilities. Write a routine that checks whether a number is prime. Check if it’s even, and if not, check all the odd numbers up to the square root of the number (do you see why the square root is enough?). If the number is not prime, tell the user one factor.
> > > >
> > > > For you demo, you’ll use Mersenne 67, which is 2 to the 67th power minus 1 (see problem 1-4-A): 147573952589676412927 [147,573,952,589,676,412,927]. In 1644, Marin Mersenne conjectured this number was prime. It was not until 1903 that F.N. Cole resolved this conjecture, for which he received a standing ovation at a meeting of the American Mathematical Society. What was the resolution? (i.e., is Mersenne 67 prime?) Use your program to answer this question; your program will probably run for about 2½ minutes, quite an advance over the 2½ centuries it originally took to resolve the issue.

This what what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to run where I can verify my answer. Any inputs would greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
def me():
    N = int(input("What is the Value of N?="))
    Mersenne=(2**N)-1
    print(format(Mersenne,',d'))

me()
```

How do I include the Merseene code above to this?

```
'''
This function takes a single argument n and returns either
1) a factor of n     if n is not prime
2) False             if n is prime
'''
def is_prime(n):
# "Check if it's even..."
if is_even(n):
    # (do something)
else:
    # "... and if not, check all the odd numbers up to the square root of the number"
    for f in <something that generates odd numbers>:
        if is_factor(f,n):
            # (do something)

# Default case:
#    n is odd, and 
#    none of the odd numbers up to sqrt(n) are factors of n
# (do something)


def get_n():
n = raw_input("What is the value of n? ")
return ((2 ** 67)-1) if n == 'm' else int(n)


n = get_n()  
p = is_prime(n)

if p:
  print("%d is not prime (e.g. factor=%d)" % (n, p))
else:
  print("%d is prime")
```

Comment: So far, all this code does is ask for *N* then print (2 ^ *N*)-1 -- which it does fine.  But there's more to your assignment than that.

Comment: Would you be able to show me? How do I implement my code to get to Merseene 67? Don't I just plug in the number and I will be fine?

Comment: As @jedwards pointed out, you're just *printing* the number with your code above. Your requirement is ***prove*** that Mersenne 67 is a prime number. Simply printing it *doesn't prove anything*.

Comment: I just changed my post... How do implement it? Towards the end, middle? I'm confused as to why and if I can see it it would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to break your problem up into sections, i.e. to start you off it asks for your program to be able to figure out if a number is even or not. This snippet does exactly that:

```
def isEven(input):
    return input % 2 == 0
```

What this function does, is modulo the input by 2 to safely determine whether or not it is even.

```
>>> isEven(10)
True
>>> isEven(9)
False
>>> isEven(144)
True
>>> isEven(67890)
True
>>> isEven(67891)
False
```

Hopefully this gets you on the right track :)

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I try to fund your code. So do I need to implement my code to yours? I'm confused because I'm trying to run the Mersenne Numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode that may or may not help

```
'''
This function takes a single argument n and returns either
    1) a factor of n     if n is not prime
    2) False             if n is prime
'''
def is_prime(n):
    # "Check if it's even..."
    if is_even(n):
        # (do something)
    else:
        # "... and if not, check all the odd numbers up to the square root of the number"
        for f in <something that generates odd numbers>:
            if is_factor(f,n):
                # (do something)

    # Default case:
    #    n is odd, and 
    #    none of the odd numbers up to sqrt(n) are factors of n
    # (do something)


def get_n():
    n = raw_input("What is the value of n? ")
    return ((2 ** 67)-1) if n == 'm' else int(n)


n = get_n()
p = is_prime(n)

if p:
    print("%d is not prime (e.g. factor=%d)" % (n, p))
else:
    print("%d is prime")
```

Note that `is_even` and `is_factor` are not real functions, you'd have to either implement them yourself or change them to equivalent operations.  Also, `<something that generates odd numbers>` isn't real either, same thing.

Also, `get_n()` is a little function that prompts a user for an integer and returns it.  If the user enters `m` (the single, lower case character), then it returns Mersenne 67 (= (2^67) - 1)

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting an error when I try to run your code... I'm getting this error....                                          File "<stdin>", line 5
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
Unknown error.

Comment: You won't be able to copy and paste the code and have it work.  You have to figure out how to implement the missing parts.

Comment: Which is the code I have originally right? The Mersenne number?

Comment: No, the assignment is to write a function that determines whether a given number is prime -- any number.  You should then test your function against Mersenne 67 to determine whether **it** is prime.

Comment: So do I implement my code in the beginning and if Merseene 67 and find out if it is prime or not? (Which would be using your implementation?)